# Polynomial long division - How does this -2x become positive

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

[image]

I cannot see how this works, where the insertion point is on the image there is a $$-x^2$$

How does it then become positive on the next line?

I realsise there is nothing for it to subtract from above, but cannot see how it suddenly becomes positive. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can say there is $0$ and so $0-(-x^2)=x^2$.

Comment: Thankyou ! it has been a long day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just realised $$0 - (-x^2) = x^2$$. oops

Comment: The way it was taught to me in high school, and the way I taught it myself later was to fill in the missing entries on each horizontal row when you write that line down. Thus, the top row would be $x^3 + 0x^2 + 0x - 1.$